# IE 8 getSelection().anchorOffset alternative

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, getselection

I have got a Javascript code, which works well for modern browsers:

```
var offset = getSelection().anchorOffset;
var node   = getSelection().anchorNode;
```

How can I get the same result on IE 8, which does not have window.getSelection() method?

Comment: I will rephrase: I need to get carret position in IE 8 and anchor node of selection :) How do they do it in IE < 9? tx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution. It is possible to extend browser's object model using [Rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/) library:

```
window.getSelection = rangy.getSelection
```

As it may take some time for Rangy to init and as we will not need this for modern browsers, some more workaround:

```
/* 
IE 8 getSelection() missing object and properties simple hack
*/
if (window.getSelection == undefined) {                /* IE? */
    var wgS = setInterval(function(){                  /* wait for Rangy */
        if (rangy.initialized) {
            window.getSelection = rangy.getSelection;  /* do the stuff */
            clearTimeout(wgS);                         /* exit */
        }
     }, 10);
}
```