# How to make containsNode() work in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have 5 paras and I wanna confirm which paras are selected.

```
<p>The 1st paragraph. Hello everyone.Nice meeting you!</p>
<p>The 2nd paragraph. Hello everyone.Nice meeting you!</p>
<p>The 3rd paragraph. Hello everyone.Nice meeting you!</p>
<p>The 4th paragraph. Hello everyone.Nice meeting you!</p>
<p>The 5th paragraph. Hello everyone.Nice meeting you!</p>
```

JS codes are as below:

```
var para = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    var result = [];

    document.onmouseup = function(){
        var selectText = window.getSelection();//get the selected range obj,ie9+ support getSelection()
        if(selectText.toString()){
            for (var i = 0;i<para.length;i++){
                if(selectText.containsNode(para[i],true)){
                    result.push(i+1);//get sequence number of the selected paras
                }
            }
            alert(result);
            result = [];
        }
    }
```

When I select texts like this:

[image: Snapshot]

Window alerts "1,2,3",which means I selected 1st,2nd and 3rd para.

But this doesn't work in IE.I searched the info and knew that IE doesn't support the method containsNode().  How to make containsNode() work in IE or use some other methods to get the same result?

PS: when selecting texts like:

[image: snapshot2]

why it alerts "1,2" ?

Comment: It looks to me as if you selected the line break from the first to the second paragraph. This practically "spans from the end of the line to the start of the new one", so both paragraphs would be involved. Try copy and pasting that selection into an empty text editor and check if there is a new line.

Answer (score 0):

It should work in IE9+, for lower version below is the link

"[IE 8 getSelection().anchorOffset alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871180/ie-8-getselection-anchoroffset-alternative)"
you can take help

Comment: It doesn't work in IE9+. It's not about the getSelection(),but containsNode().