# jQuery issue when .find() term in variable with more than one match

Tags: javascript, jquery

My aim is to let the user select text with the cursor and output the selection into a different div with the highlighted text in `<span>` tags.

So, I have the selection set like this:

```
var sel = jQuery.selection();
```

And then I wrap the selection into `<span>` and output it:

```
var $title = jQuery(this).parent().find('.title').text();
var $result;
$result = $title.replace(sel, '<span>'+sel+'</span>');

// output result
jQuery(this).parent().find('.output').html($result);
```

It works fine.

The problem is that if the text contain the same term twice and the user selects the second term, it will find and replace the first term.

For example, random text:

```
hello world lorem ipsum hello
```

If user selects the second `hello`, it will wrap the first one.

Is there a solution to apply to solve this type of scenario?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sqd5gsz5/2/) for testing.

Comment: I will bounty this question with 50 points when eligible.

Comment: This is actually quite an interesting issue +1 -- I wonder if there is a way to to target the specific find match when doing replace()...

Comment: you mean to say is user select second term then first term should not be changed

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sqd5gsz5/1/

Comment: if you wonder, why it works for 1st and 2nd hello ... it's case sensitive

Comment: It doesnt work with 3rd "hello" in chrome

Comment: What is the kind of browser support needed, the `$.selection` does not provide a way to do that...

Comment: Whether the title will have only a single text node, or can it have other child elements also?

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks for the jsFiddle, please see my updated one: https://jsfiddle.net/sqd5gsz5/2/ The title div only contains plain text. No child elements etc.

Comment: @GeneR It's because the first hello was in capitals. find() is case sensitive. Please test the following jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sqd5gsz5/2/

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Please state browser compatibility requirements since this is crucial for the answer to your question (altough a working answer has been given) ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the offset from which you can start replacing ...

```
$('button').click(function() {
  var sel = jQuery.selection();
  var $title = jQuery(this).parent().find('.title').text();
  var $result;
  var highlightFrom = window.getSelection().anchorOffset;


    $result = $title.substr(0,highlightFrom) + $title.substr(highlightFrom, $title.length).replace(sel, '<span>' + sel + '</span>');


  // output result
  jQuery(this).parent().find('.output').text($result);
});
```

In your sample, highlighfrom gives 24 when selecting second hello.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Yoeri/sqd5gsz5/5/)

AnchorOffset is supported by IE9+ and other major browsers.
If you need a valid alternative, I refer to Rangy as stated here:
[AnchorOffset alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871180/ie-8-getselection-anchoroffset-alternative)

See [here for more info on textselection ranges and browser compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html)

***TESTED*** - Chrome, IE11+, FF

Comment: This is an experimental technology (works in chrome tho) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/anchorOffset

Comment: While this does give the desired output. As stated by Gene, there is a matter of browser compatibility. Thank you for posting regardless.

Comment: @lukbl he is worried about compatibility with anchorOffset, not replace?

Comment: I'm thinking the best approach here is to do a "if (window.getSelection) " and just stick with the find/replace I already have for IE8 users. They don't deserve any better anyway. I'm going to test your approach on a number of devices and report back.

Comment: Works great with the if statement. The bounty will be rewarded soon to you! ;)

Answer (score 0):

i know, there is still an issue with browser compatibility, using the anchor offsets. but the first thing, i came up with, would be slicing the given string into three parts. the part before the selection, the selected part and the rest.
then wrapping the selected part and put them together again...

```
$('button').click(function() {
  var $sel = jQuery.selection();
  var $highlightStart = window.getSelection().anchorOffset;
  var $highlightEnd = window.getSelection().focusOffset;

  var $title = jQuery(this).parent().find('.title').text();
  var $textLength = $title.length;

  var $textBefore = $title.substr(0,$highlightStart);
  var $textToWrap = $title.substr($highlightStart, $highlightEnd - $highlightStart);
  var $textAfter = $title.substr($highlightEnd, $textLength - $highlightEnd);

  var $result;
  $result = $textBefore + '<span>' + $textToWrap + '</span>' + $textAfter;

  // output result
  jQuery(this).parent().find('.output').text($result);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sqd5gsz5/6/